# Storm Kafka Spout Unable to read last off read

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using storm-kafka-0.9.3 to read data from the Kafka and process those data in Storm. Below is the Kafka Spout I am using.But the problem is when I kill the Storm cluster, it does not read old data which was sent during the time it was dead, it start reading from the latest offset.

```java
BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(Constants.ZOOKEEPER_HOST);

SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, CommonConstants.KAFKA_TRANSACTION_TOPIC_NAME
        , "/" + CommonConstants.KAFKA_TRANSACTION_TOPIC_NAME,UUID.randomUUID().toString());
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
//Never should make this true
spoutConfig.forceFromStart=false;
spoutConfig.startOffsetTime =-2;

KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
return kafkaSpout;
```

Comment: can you please try comment out `spoutConfig.forceFromStart=false;` line or by set `spoutConfig.forceFromStart=true`

Comment: Tried that but same issue, see actually Assume I have 100 messages in kafka, Storm processing that, Now assume after 100th message Storm went down and my http end point pushed 300 more messages in Kafka, Since Storm processed only 100 message I expect when Storm wakes up it should start processing from 101 message where it left.

Comment: so what exactly happening ? in your post you've mentioned it start reading from the latest offset .. isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Basically when strom comes back it starts reading from 401 instead of 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks All,
Since I was running the Topology in Local mode,Storm did not store Offset in ZK, when I ran the topology in Prod mode It got resolved.

Sougata

Comment: So what configurations helped you solving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might happen because while the topology is running it used to keep all the state information to zookeeper using the following path `SpoutConfig.zkRoot+ "/" + SpoutConfig.id` so that in case of failure it can resume from the last written offset in zookeeper.

Got this from the doc

> **Important**:When re-deploying a topology make sure that the settings for SpoutConfig.zkRoot and SpoutConfig.id were not modified, otherwise the spout will not be able to read its previous consumer state information (i.e. the offsets) from ZooKeeper -- which may lead to unexpected behavior and/or to data loss, depending on your use case.

In your case as the `SpoutConfig.id` is a random value `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` Its not able to retrieve the last committed offset.

Also read from the same page

> when a topology has run once the setting **KafkaConfig.startOffsetTime will not have an effect for subsequent runs** of the topology because now the topology will rely on the consumer state information (offsets) in ZooKeeper to determine from where it should begin (more precisely: resume) reading. If you want to force the spout to ignore any consumer state information stored in ZooKeeper, then you should set the parameter **KafkaConfig.ignoreZkOffsets to true**. If true, the spout will always begin reading from the offset defined by KafkaConfig.startOffsetTime as described above

You could possibly use a static `id` to see if it is able to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still not working as expected SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, CommonConstants.KAFKA_TRANSACTION_TOPIC_NAME
                , "/" + CommonConstants.KAFKA_TRANSACTION_TOPIC_NAME,"Test");spoutConfig.forceFromStart=true;

Comment: as per my understanding you are doing this - 1) Start kafka-spout to read 100 msg (2) Kill the topology (3) Push 100 more msg in the queue (4) strat the topology again  .. and it start reading from 201 offset .. is this correct ?

Comment: Yes it starts from 201, But I want it should start from 101, as it did not process last 100 messages. BTW I have used trident also its the same issue. It always reads from 201.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the spoutConfig.zkServers and spoutConfig.zkPort :

```
BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(Constants.ZOOKEEPER_HOST);
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts,  CommonConstants.KAFKA_TRANSACTION_TOPIC_NAME
    , "/" + CommonConstants.KAFKA_TRANSACTION_TOPIC_NAME,"test");

spoutConfig.zkPort=Constants.ZOOKEEPER_PORT;  
spoutConfig.zkServers=Constants.ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS;

spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());

KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);
return kafkaSpout;
```